# Intent Service Time Interval Not maintained

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-intentservice

I have created an intent service which should send data to the server at a userdefined interval, but in my case time, the interval is not maintained correctly by alarm manager. Can u guide where I m doing error. I want to run the service while the device in sleep or idle mode too. Here is my code.

```
   public void sosalarmson() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, AlarmReceiver.receivercode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), Integer.parseInt(userdefinedinterval) *60* 1000, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(FinalSettings.this, "alarm On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Ideally, if I give user input as 15, so alarm should send intent at 15 mins, whereas it is sending at 10mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this code and it is working perfectly:

define:

```
final int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
AlarmManager al;
PendingIntent fintent;
Intent notif;
```

i am directly start service using alarm manager._alarm is your predefined interval.

```
long _alarm;

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar wakeupcall = Calendar.getInstance();
        wakeupcall.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        wakeupcall.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        wakeupcall.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

        if (wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() <= now.getTimeInMillis())
            _alarm=wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY+1);
        else
            _alarm=wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis();

al = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        notif= new Intent(this,TestNotifyService.class);
        fintent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0,notif,0);

if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            al.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_alarm, fintent);
        }
        else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT  && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            al.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_alarm,fintent);
        }
        else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            al.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_alarm,fintent);
        }
```

Comment: you used RTC instead of ElapsedTime, though as per docs, RTC does not count time when it is in sleep mode (wall clock time in UTC). still it can be used?

Comment: I am using this code to run every day at 22:00. And it is executing  exact time period.

Comment: one point is clear that if i want to run at interval of 15 mins, i will replace _alarm with 15*60*1000. But where to put time like want to fire intent at 20.00 hrs.

Comment: i m using code your but it is not calling pending intent. any idea.

Comment: what happens when you run app?

Comment: it shows alarm has set as per conditions but not calling pending intent later. like in my case, i have android m, so got log for it. i set time for say 10.15 earlier when it was 10.05 and called the method. but nothing happened on 10.15.

Comment: what you are doing in pending intent?

Comment: Pending intent is class extending to intentservice and it send one mail to defined email id. i have put log their also to check whether call goes to class or not, but it does not even send call to pending intent class.

Comment: have you use WAKE_LOG to execute intent service? post your pending intent intialization methods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131650/discussion-between-ankur-jain-and-divyesh).